# Robocopy fails with error 121 when running in a new window of conemu

Tags: robocopy, conemu

I have a long running process that spans robocopy windows to parallelize copying process. It goes well under cmd.exe, but when I try it under conemu, child windows has the following message:

> ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
>   Press Enter or Esc to close console...

And parent window:

> [2015-07-08 09:57:20] Error: Could not copy xxxxx. Robocopy ExitCode: 121.

How can  I debug and fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your batch uses `start` to start new console with `robocopy`. You may disable `start` processing in the [ConEmu's Settings](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsFeatures.html). Or may be you are using old ConEmu version. Actually there may be other issues but without exact information nobody can tell you more.